# Finding the Estimated Standard Error of a 10%/90% data division estimator

Tags: point-estimation

I am learning about estimated standard error of an estimator, which is defined as the square root of the variance of the estimator: $\sqrt{V(\Theta)}$

Given the data, assumed to be from a normal distribution: .83 .88 .88 1.04 1.09 1.12 1.29 1.31 1.48 1.49 1.59 1.62 1.65 1.71 1.76 1.83

I found an estimator for dividing the top 10% from the bottom 90% as: $1.28\cdot \sigma + \mu$

And now I'm supposed to find the estimate for the standard error.  I'm not quite sure what to do.  The correct answer is .0905.

I found my estimate for $\sigma$ to be 0.3385 and my estimate for $\mu$ to be 1.348, using sample variance and sample mean.  My first thought was my estimated standard error would be sqrt(1.28*0.3385+1.348), but that is incorrect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you may need to divide the standard deviation by $\sqrt{n}$, since you are about to use a statistic $\bar{X}$ to estimate $\mu$ but it is not 0.0905. 0.0385/4=0.0846

Comment: And I don't understand the meaning  of this."I found an estimator for dividing the top 10% from the bottom 90% as: $1.28\cdot \sigma + \mu$"

Comment: @Deep North I am trying to find an estimator for the value that divides the top 10% of values from the bottom 90%.

Comment: @Dwin -- Why wouldn't the sample mean be inside the square root? Since my estimator is $1.28\sigma + \mu$, and the estimated standard error is the square root of the variance of the estimator, I need the variance of $1.28\sigma + \mu$, and then take the square root of that.

Comment: Never mind. I've appeared to cause more confusion than light.